# SELECT duplicate columns in MYSQL database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table titled **products**.

I have 2 columns in the table titled **name** and **image**

I have 4 entries in my database

```
item 1 | image1.jpg
item 2 | image1.jpg
item 3 | image1.jpg
item 4 | image2.jpg
```

I need to display the results on a page but I only need to display image.1jpg once, my while() loop is obviously displaying all 4 images.

I've been at this for hours, please help!

My code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' ORDER BY id ASC");

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){  

$image = $fetch['image'];
$name = $fetch['name'];

echo ''.$name.'';
echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail_image.'"/>';   

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' ORDER BY id ASC`?

Comment: `("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' ORDER BY id ASC")`

Doesn't work, but thanks for the help

Comment: Oh, of course it does not, my bad, your are selectin everything from the table. If you want only unique images.jpg change it to `SELECT DISTINCT image FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' ORDER BY id ASC`. You should get image1.jpg and image2.jpg now.

Comment: @drive235 you're a star, thank you. Although, this only grabs the image and will not echo the **name**

Comment: Which name do you want echoed? Amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @JamesOsguthorpe Have you tried using `SELECT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' GROUP BY image ORDER BY id ASC` ?

Comment: @Javad Let's hope not.

Comment: @Javad you legend! It works! Lets now all pretend I tried that straight away and get on with our lives! Haha! 

Thanks everyone, appreciate it the help.

Comment: @JamesOsguthorpe There you go; good luck

Comment: @Javad: You should put that as an answer instead of just leaving it as a comment. That way the asker can mark it as answered.

Comment: @Javad - unable to, not enough rep

Comment: @CanSpice I put it; I thought it's a simple thing though I just comment it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' GROUP BY image ORDER BY id ASC");

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){  

$image = $fetch['image'];
$name = $fetch['name'];

echo ''.$name.'';
echo '<img src="'.$thumbnail_image.'"/>';   

}
```

Comment: I have amended my answer @James Osguthorpe

Answer (score 1):

What you need is using `GROUP BY` in your query. So change the query as

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE page='Birthdays' GROUP BY image ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a trick like not using while statement at all. If you just write the 
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) without while you would just get the first result in the query. I hope this helps.